# ASP.net MVC 2 - Using textbox with linq

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using LINQ and sending a linq object to the view and trying to show it in a textbox like this

```
<%=Html.TextBox("petname",Model.PetName) %>
```

But I am getting error, please suggest how can I show (PetRecord.PetName) which is my linq entity

Thanks 
Raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your `Inherits` property look like:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

It should inherit whatever model you're sending to the view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<PetRecord>" %>
```

And you should be sending the following to your view from the controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowPet(int petId)
{
    PetRecord pet = repository.GetPetById(petId);
    return View(pet);
}
```

Comment: PetRecord is my linq entity name not my model ?

Comment: cant I use System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>?

Comment: @RHM What does the view look like? What error are you getting? It's really tough to psychically debug your issue.

Comment: I am looking into this and will let you know, Thanks George.

Comment: @RHM what ended up being the problem?